# How to get attendees list from event with Google Calendar API in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-calendar-api

I'm currently coding a react.js web page for meetings using https://github.com/sivadass/react-meeting-room And i want to print the participants below the event but the array of the events I get doesn't contain the participants.

Here is my part of the code that gets my events :

```
.then(function() {
      return gapi.client.request({
        path: 
`https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/${CALENDAR_ID}/events?maxResults=11&orderBy=updated&timeMin=${moment().toISOString()}&timeMax=${moment()
          .endOf("day")
          .toISOString()}`
      });
    })
```

With this I get "mymeetingroom@resource.calendar.google.com" as the only participant. This is using the Google APIs.